# When two unbiased dice are rolled one by one, what is the probability that either the first one is $2$ or the sum of the two is less than $5$?

Tags: probability

> When two unbiased dice are rolled one by one, what is the probability that either the first one is $2$ or the sum of the two is less than $5$?
>
> a) $\dfrac 16$
>
> b) $\dfrac 29$
>
> c) $\dfrac 5{18}$
>
> d) $\dfrac 13$
>
> *(Not homework, I'm doing some mock exams I found online)*

Now I was pretty sure I got this. Take probability of rolling $2$ on the first one $\left(\frac 16\right)$ and the probability that the sum is $< 5 \left(\frac 6{36}\right)$, add them together and bam, $\frac 13$.

Wrong, seems the answer is c) $\frac5{18}$.

My problem is I've been trying to brush on my probability skills by googling and can see problems I made, such as the wording meaning that rolling a $2$ AND having a total of $5$ NOT being included in the result, but no matter what angle I attack from, I never end up with $\frac5{18}$.

So which little thing did I miss? Thanks very much for helping.

Comment: You should identify the sample space first. [Here](http://www.analyzemath.com/statistics/two_dice_outcomes.gif) is a graphical representation.

Comment: See also, the first line under "probability" in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First consider things intuitively**

We have the following table for adding the dice together

$$\begin{array}{|cc|cccccc|}\hline
&&&&&D_1\\
&&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
&1&\color{red}2&\color{red}3&\color{red}4&5&6&7\\
&2&\color{red}3&\color{red}4&5&6&7&8\\
D_2&3&\color{red}4&\color{red}5&6&7&8&9\\
&4&5&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10\\
&5&6&\color{red}7&8&9&10&11\\
&6&7&\color{red}8&9&10&11&12\\
\hline\end{array}$$

The red highlighted values are the ones which satisfy our conditions

We can count them to give us the answer $$P(D_1=2\text { OR }D_1+D_2<5)=\frac{10}{36}=\frac{5}{18}$$

---

**Now consider things mathematically**

We can count up $P(D_1=2)=\dfrac6{36}=\dfrac16$

$$\begin{array}{|cc|cccccc|}\hline
&&&&&D_1\\
&&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
&1&2&\color{red}3&4&5&6&7\\
&2&3&\color{red}4&5&6&7&8\\
D_2&3&4&\color{red}5&6&7&8&9\\
&4&5&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10\\
&5&6&\color{red}7&8&9&10&11\\
&6&7&\color{red}8&9&10&11&12\\
\hline\end{array}$$

We can also count up $P(D_1+D_2<5)=\dfrac 6{36}=\dfrac16$

$$\begin{array}{|cc|cccccc|}\hline
&&&&&D_1\\
&&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
&1&\color{red}2&\color{red}3&\color{red}4&5&6&7\\
&2&\color{red}3&\color{red}4&5&6&7&8\\
D_2&3&\color{red}4&5&6&7&8&9\\
&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\
&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
\hline\end{array}$$

However, note that while doing this, we counted two values twice, $(D_1,D_2)=(2,1)$ and $(D_1,D_2)=(2,2)$

$$\begin{array}{|cc|cccccc|}\hline
&&&&&D_1\\
&&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
&1&2&\color{red}3&4&5&6&7\\
&2&3&\color{red}4&5&6&7&8\\
D_2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\
&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
\hline\end{array}$$

So we must then subtract $\dfrac2{36}=\dfrac1{18}$ from our answer, giving

\begin{align}P(D_1=2\text { OR }D_1+D_2<5)&=P(D_1=2)+P(D_1+D_2<5)-P(D_1=2\text { AND }D_1+D_2<5)\\
&=\frac16+\frac16-\frac1{18}\\
&=\frac 5{18}\end{align}

Comment: Ahh so I found the right way to go about it but just goofed and did it wrong. I only subtracted one overlap. Also the intuitive table, of cause! I even made one myself, but somehow fudged up the way to mark case 1... Thanks this helped get me back in the right mindset.

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the probability that either the first die is $2$, OR the sum is less than $5$. In math, "OR" always includes the possibility that both things occur (i.e. "either A or B" includes when A and B both happen).

However, you added the probability that the first die was $2$ ($6/36$) and the probability that the sum was less than $5$ ($6/36$)-- that means that in the case that both occur, you counted it twice, since it will be included in both first term and the second term. This is called *double-counting*. To fix double-counting, you need to subtract off what you counted twice.

In this case, what you counted twice is when the first die is $2$ AND the sum is less than $5$ -- this happens if the two dice are $(2,1)$ or $(2,2)$, so the probability is $2/36$. Your final answer will be
$$
\frac{6}{36} + \frac{6}{36} - \frac{2}{36} = \frac{10}{36} = \frac{5}{18}.
$$

Comment: thank you very much. I only subtracted one possibility in my later attempts.